# land that temporarily became a land creature and the graveyard

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm casting [Wrenn and Realmbreaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrenn%20and%20Realmbreaker). I'm using her +1 to make a land a creature until my next turn. My opponent during his turn casts [Invoke Despair](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Invoke%20Despair) and so I have to sacrifice my land creature (as its my only one). I'd like to rescue it though, so in response I'm casting [Not Dead After All](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Not%20Dead%20After%20All). As a consequence of the land creature going to the graveyard, does it lose its (temporary) creature type, and therefore does not come back to the battlefield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The land card is not a creature card in the graveyard, but that doesn't matter for Not Dead After All: the card still returns to the battlefield, but it can't get a Wicked Role because it is not a creature after it comes back.

The spell Not Dead After All affects "target creature", so the permanent needs to be a creature at that time to get the ability, but the ability it grants doesn't actually care. It says "this creature", but that is just another way of saying "this permanent". After that, the ability doesn't check in any way that the card still has the creature type once it moves to the graveyard, so that doesn't make a difference in how the rest of the effect is handled.

The Wicked Role is defined in [rule 111.10q](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Token):

> A Wicked Role token is a colorless Aura Role enchantment token named Wicked with **enchant creature**, “Enchanted creature gets +1/+1,” and “When this Aura is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, each opponent loses 1 life.”

Since it has "enchant creature", it cannot legally be attached to the land that returns, so that part of the effect just doesn't happen.

Comment: Is there a rule that makes it clear that the aura token is not created but then goes to the graveyard because it cannot be attached to something?

Comment: I see the ruling on Not Dead After All that says this; but not sure which rule makes it that way.

Comment: Rule 303.4i: "If an effect attempts to put an Aura onto the battlefield attached to either an object or player it can’t legally enchant or an object or player that is undefined, the Aura remains in its current zone, unless that zone is the stack. In that case, the Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard instead of entering the battlefield. If the Aura is a token, it isn’t created."